# How to consume last N messages (roughly) from a topic of M unbalanced partitions in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I have a need to consume last N messages from a Kafka topic.

The topic has M partitions, each due to whatever reason has more or less messages than others. In other words, messages are not evenly distributed across partitions.

What would be the logic (let it be pseudo code) that achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the number of messages N is from all the partitions?

Comment: Yes. (placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import confluent_kafka
import time

conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': '10.164.x.x:9092,10.164.x.x:9092,10.164.x.x:9092',
    'group.id': 'kafka_consumer',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
}

topic_name = '<your_topic_name>'
my_consumer = confluent_kafka.Consumer(conf)


def get_topic_partitions(topic_name):
    """
        Get topic partitions objects. This objects contains metadata as the partition offset.
    """
    topic = my_consumer.list_topics(topic=topic_name, timeout=15)
    partitions = topic.topics[topic_name].partitions
    return partitions


def get_partition_offsets(topic_name, partition_key, timeout=15):
    """
        Extract the offsets (low_offset, high_offset) from partition object
    """
    topic_partition = confluent_kafka.TopicPartition(topic_name, partition_key)
    low_offset, high_offset = my_consumer.get_watermark_offsets(topic_partition, timeout=timeout)
    return partition_key, low_offset, high_offset


def get_topic_partitions_offsets(topic_name: str):
    """
        Extract all topic partitions offsets (multithreading)
    """
    partitions = get_topic_partitions(topic_name)
    workers, max_workers = [], max(200, len(partitions) or 1)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as e:
        for partition_key in list(partitions.keys()):
            job = e.submit(get_partition_offsets, topic_name, partition_key)
            workers.append(job)

    partitions_offsets = dict()
    for w in workers:
        partition_key, low_offset, high_offset = w.result()
        partitions_offsets[partition_key] = (low_offset, high_offset)

    return partitions_offsets


def assign_topic_partitions(topic_name):
    topic_partitions = []
    topic_partitions_offsets = get_topic_partitions_offsets(topic_name)
    for partition_key, (low_offset, high_offset) in topic_partitions_offsets.items():
        partition = confluent_kafka.TopicPartition(topic_name, partition_key)
        partition.offset = low_offset  # Set by default, the lowest available offset. Avoid "Offset out of range" error
        topic_partitions.append(partition)

    my_consumer.assign(topic_partitions)
    time.sleep(1)  # Don't seek to fast before assigning the partitions; wait at least 1 second to give brokers time to process the assign request.

    return topic_partitions


def reset_partitions_offsets(topic_name: str, topics_partitions, last_n_messages_per_partition: int):
    topic_partitions_offsets = get_topic_partitions_offsets(topic_name)
    for partition_key, (low_offset, high_offset) in topic_partitions_offsets.items():
        partition = topics_partitions[partition_key]
        new_offset = min(max(high_offset - last_n_messages_per_partition, low_offset), high_offset)  # Keep the offset in the [min, max] interval; e.q valid interval

        partition.offset = new_offset
        my_consumer.seek(partition)


def read_last_n_messages(n):
    topic_partitions = assign_topic_partitions(topic_name)  # Call this method only one time; before starting consuming !!!

    reset_partitions_offsets(topic_name, topic_partitions, last_n_messages_per_partition=n)  # Set how many messages you want to read per partition !!!!
    while True:
        avro_message = my_consumer.poll(timeout=5)

        if avro_message:
            print("Topic: {} -- Partition: {} -- Offset: {}".format(avro_message.topic(), avro_message.partition(), avro_message.offset()))
            print(avro_message)  # I didn't add the deserialization part done normally by Schema Registry
        else:
            print("No new message in the Kafka Topic")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_last_n_messages(10)
```